# SQL, grant user with only readaccess, to execute stored procedure to insert, delete, drop etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

I've tried to find the answer but this scenario seems to be unique or unusual.
Running SQL 2008 and 2012. We'd like to set up a user that can only read data, and execute stored procedures, and view the stored procedure definition (the last bit is optional). Let's call this user "servicedesk". I've also created a role called "Exec_sps"

The stored procedures should be able to insert, update, delete, drop table. But the user "servicedesk" should not be able to do this at all. Only via a stored procedure. And the user should not be able to alter the procedure itself of course.

I've managed to create proof of concept by adding execute to a role, and adding user "servicedesk" to this role. But when I do, the user "helpdesk" always gets higher permission to alter the stored procedure as well, which we want to avoid.

So basically, give low access to user, user can execute to stored procedure, and alot of permissions to that procedure, without the user inheriting the access of the stored procedures.

Is it doable?

Regards

Comment: Why do you want this role to be able to view the definition of your procedure? That seems quite silly. They can view the logic but can't do anything. If they can't be trusted with the data why should they be trusted to view the logic that does?

Comment: Hi. 
Actually viewing the definition of stored procedure is not mandatory. The important thing is that the user can "correct" data via a stored procedure, without being able to modify anything with it's own privilgies, outside of the stored procedure.

Comment: I suppose you could execute the stored procedures as someone with higher privileges. e.g. `create proc myproc with execute as 'myadminaccount' as begin...`

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and it seems to work as intended. I got other problems now, like how to impersonate a user in one procedure, but fetch data from other database. But that's another issue and I found some links about that.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The requirements seem odd to me, but this seems to work within SQL 2012.

Run this script as [sa] or a login with membership in fixed server role [sysadmin]:

```
CREATE LOGIN ServiceDesk
WITH PASSWORD = '123ABCdef'

USE YourDatabase
GO

CREATE USER SDUser
FOR LOGIN ServiceDesk
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Stooge(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(32)
)

CREATE PROC dbo.AddStooge
    @StoogeName VARCHAR(32)
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.Stooge(Name) VALUES(@StoogeName);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.UpdateStooge
    @StoogeId INT,
    @NewName VARCHAR(32)
AS
UPDATE dbo.Stooge
SET Name = @NewName
WHERE ID = @StoogeId
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.DeleteStooge
    @StoogeId INT
AS 
DELETE FROM dbo.Stooge
WHERE ID = @StoogeId
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.DropStoogeTable
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND t.TABLE_NAME = 'Stooge')
    DROP TABLE dbo.Stooge;
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER SDUser
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.AddStooge TO SDUser
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.UpdateStooge TO SDUser
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.DeleteStooge TO SDUser
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.DropStoogeTable TO SDUser
```

Now connect as the login [ServiceDesk] (created above) and run the script commands one at a time:

```
USE YourDatabase
GO
--[SDUser] should be able to select from any table.
SELECT * FROM dbo.Stooge

--[SDUser] should be able to execute [AddStooge] proc.
EXEC dbo.AddStooge 'Larry'
EXEC dbo.AddStooge 'Carly'
EXEC dbo.AddStooge 'Moo'

--verify stooges added.
SELECT * FROM dbo.Stooge

--Fix spelling mistake. [SDUser] should be able to execute [UpdateStooge] proc.
EXEC dbo.UpdateStooge 2, 'Curley'

--Verify updated stooge
SELECT * FROM dbo.Stooge

--[SDUser] should be able to execute [DeleteStooge] proc.
EXEC dbo.DeleteStooge 3

--Verify deleted stooge
SELECT * FROM dbo.Stooge

--This should fail. [SDUser] should not be able to alter proc.
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteStooge
    @StoogeId INT
AS
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Stooge WHERE ID = @StoogeId )
        RAISERROR('Stooge does not exist', 16, 1);
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM dbo.Stooge
        WHERE ID = @StoogeId
GO

--[SDUser] should not be able to view the proc definition. ([ROUTINE_DEFINITION] is null)
SELECT r.ROUTINE_NAME, r.ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
WHERE r.ROUTINE_NAME = 'DeleteStooge'
GO

--[SDUser] should be able to execute [DropStoogeTable] proc.
EXEC dbo.DropStoogeTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these examples, and see what happens.